# Loop and remove empty element with jquery

Tags: jquery

Im so close but just can't quite get there.

I want to add a class display:none to the div if the spans inside it are empty.

html:

```
 <div class="accordion-content default">
    <div><span><?php the_field(''); ?></span><span><?php the_field('tenure1'); ?></span></div>
    <div><span><?php the_field(''); ?></span><span><?php the_field('tenure2'); ?></span></div>
    <div><span><?php the_field(''); ?></span><span><?php the_field('tenure3'); ?></span></div>
    <div><span><?php the_field(''); ?></span><span><?php the_field('tenure4'); ?></span></div>
    <div><span><?php the_field(''); ?></span><span><?php the_field('tenure5'); ?></span></div>
    <div><span><?php the_field(''); ?></span><span><?php the_field('tenure6'); ?></span></div>
    <div><span><?php the_field(''); ?></span><span><?php the_field('tenure7'); ?></span></div>
    <div><span><?php the_field(''); ?></span><span><?php the_field('tenure8'); ?></span></div>
    <div><span><?php the_field(''); ?></span><span><?php the_field('tenure9'); ?></span></div>
    <div><span><?php the_field(''); ?></span><span><?php the_field('tenure10'); ?></span></div>
    <div><span>Yearsl</span><span><?php the_field(''); ?></span></div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
   //hide unused fields
//iterate over each div
$('.accordion-content div').each(function(i, obj) {
// if the spans it contain are empty
if ($('span:empty').html().length == 0 ) {
//do not display the parent div
$('.accordion-content div').css({'display' : 'none'});
    };
});
```

Thanks.

EDIT: Currently it removes all the divs not just the ones with empty span tags.

Comment: Who's downvoting and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two main problems:

1. `$('span:empty')` searches the entire document for a empty span, and calling `html()` on the result accesses the HTML of the first match. You want to look *within* the div via `$(this).find("span:empty")`.
2. `$('.accordion-content div').css({'display' : 'none'});` hides **all** matching elements.

Also, no need to call `html()`, you know it's empty, and jQuery has a builtin function for setting `display: none` on elements: `hide`.

If you want to hide the div if *any* span inside it is empty, then:

```
$('.accordion-content div:has(span:empty)').hide();
```

If you want to hide the div if *all* spans inside it are empty, then:

```
$('.accordion-content div').filter(function(i, obj) {
    return $(this).find('span:parent').length == 0;
}).hide();
```

That will also hide the div if it doesn't have any spans at all, so for completeness, this hides ones that have spans, but only empty ones:

```
$('.accordion-content div:has(span)').filter(function(i, obj) {
    return $(this).find('span:parent').length == 0;
}).hide();
```

Comment: Giving +1 for use of `:parent` (as in, "where this is a parent") - I can't even use the excuse that it's new :)